# What is the difference between Cauchy's Rule and L'Hôpital's Rule?

Tags: calculus, limits

My teacher didn't mention there was a difference, but I think the two rules are not exactly equal to one another.

What is the difference between the two rules?
Is it the functions that intervene in the limit?

Thank you!

Edit: Apparently in my country there is a poor practice of calling L'Hôpital's Rule, the Cauchy's Rule.

Edit2: https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120131110851AAlLBcp

Comment: Please add your definition of "Cauchy's rule", as the search engine only finds references to series multiplication. -- Note that many things are named for Cauchy, sometimes not because he invented it but because he was the first to mention it in a widely read text book. -- L'Hopital's rule was discovered by one of the Bernoullis.

Comment: Yeah, I never heard of a Cauchy rule.  Perhaps you are thinking about quotient rule?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably thinking about [Cauchy's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Cauchy.27s_mean_value_theorem) and [l'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule). The difference is that Cauchy's theorem is used to prove the second one.

> **Cauchy's theorem.** Suppose the functions $f(x)$ and $\varphi(x)$ are continuous on the closed interval $[a,b]$ and differentiable on the open interval $(a,b).$ For simplicity, assume $$\varphi'(x)\neq0\ \ \forall x\in(a,b).$$ When these conditions are met, there exists a $c\in(a,b)$ such that $$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{\varphi(b)-\varphi(a)}=\frac{f'(c)}{\varphi'(c)}.$$

As mentioned, this fact is applied in the proving of l'Hôpital's rule. The latter simplifies many limit problems where indeterminate forms are encountered. The famous limit $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}$$ becomes straight-forward since

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=\left\{\frac{0}{0}\right\}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(\sin x)'}{x'}=\lim_{x\to0}\cos x=1. \ \ (*)$$

Also,

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{-x^3}{e^x\ln x}=\left\{\frac{\infty}{\infty}\right\}=-1\cdot\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{(x^3)'}{(e^x\ln x)'}=0.$$

Cauchy's theorem, in turn, is shown to be true via [Rolle's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem).

---

(*) Here the trigonometric functions are defined as infinite series in order to avoid circular argumentation. (See comment section below.)

Comment: Often times people find that *only* using l'Hôpital's rule in such cases is unsatisfying. Using different methods may offer geometric insight and do widen one's mathematical toolbox. Heck, the site even has a tag 'limits-without-l'Hôpital'.

Comment: I find your example of the "famous limit: a rather poor example of L'Hopital's Rule as the proving the derivative of the sine involves the very same limit you are proving with the Rule.Why not just use some rational function that has a zero over zero situation as an example instead?

Comment: @imranfat If we define the trigonometric functions as infinite series, this problem is circumvented. Though I do see your point as well. I will add the necessary comment and perhaps an additional example tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: But if $\sin$ is defined via its Maclaurin series, the fact that $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \dfrac{\sin x}{x} = 1$ is immediately obvious from the power series. While using L'H is in that setting not circular, it's gratuitous use of a non-obvious tool where an obvious one exists.

Comment: @DanielFischer Consider for instance $$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{x^x\cdot\sin x}.$$ L'Hôpital's rule is still probably one's first bet here. So the central idea holds. Nevertheless, in a moment the second example will be added as promised.

Comment: Well, _my_ first bet there is Taylor expansion, but that differs from person to person. Of course one should notice that $x^x \to 1$ as the $0^{\text{th}}$ step, so one only needs to look at $\dfrac{e^x-e^{-x}}{\sin x}$. I'm not saying that L'H shouldn't be used at all, just that the example $\dfrac{\sin x}{x}$ was unfortunately chosen,

Comment: @DanielFische +1. I'm willing to admit that it was more an unfortunate than it was an excellent example haha :)